# in Javascript how to does var myvar = value !=1 work?

Tags: javascript

I couldn't find reference to this anywhere online simply because I don't know what it is called or how to describe is.

Basically I'm reading a JavaScript book and they are showing a technique called [Memorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) using a function that calculates a prime number( see code below). What I would like to know is, is there a term for `var prime = value != 1;` and how does it work? I understand from the explanation of the entire function in the book that it means prime is assigned value but it cannot be 1. It throws no errors so does it just `break` from the code? Any Information including links would be greatly welcomed

```
function isPrime(value) {
    if (!isPrime.answers) isPrime.answers = {};
    if (isPrime.answers[value] != null) {
        return isPrime.answers[value];
    }

    var prime = value != 1; 
    for (var i = 2; i < value; i++) {
        if (value % i == 0) {
            prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isPrime.answers[value] = prime;
  }
}
```

Comment: `var prime = value != 1;` means "assign to `prime` the result of evaluating `value != 1`". That result is obviously going to be a boolean indicating if `value` is equal to 1 or not.

Comment: @Juhana sorry I did try search SO and didn't seem to get that topic earlier, if some wish to remove or close please go ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the expression right to left to understand what it means. Here the author means that the value of `prime` is boolean indicating whether `value != 1`. So if value is one the value of `prime` will be `false` and will be `true` if it is different from one.

Comment: Thank you @IvayloStrandjev , is there a name for this or is this just something basic I should be aware of already?

Comment: A name of what? It is just how many programming languages work. In fact this expression can be thought of as a shorter version of a simple if. I don't think it is good to use such expressions as they tend to be confusing(as you just proved), but once you get used to that it is not hard to understand what they do at all.

Comment: @jonnieM It's not a special construct, it's exactly the same as for example `value = 1 + 2` except that in place of `+` you just have another operator (`!=`).

Answer (score 1):

> var prime = value != 1;

You can replace this line with this:

```
if((value != 1) == true)
    prime = true;
else
    prime = false;
```

Or rephrase it:

```
if((value != 1) == true)
    prime = true;
else if((value != 1) == false)
    prime = false;
```

You see prime becomes the exact value the expression (value != 1) is. Thats why they use this handy short cut. But since this is something for teaching JS they should have written it at least: `var prime = (value != 1) ? true : false;` which is more obvious. Or even better let the code look like this:

```
function isPrime(value) {
if (!isPrime.answers) isPrime.answers = {};
if (isPrime.answers[value] != null) {
    return isPrime.answers[value];
}

if(value == 0) 
   isPrime.answers[value] = false;
else if(value == 1) 
   isPrime.answers[value] = true;
else {
   var prime = false;
   for (var i = 2; i < value; i++) {
      if (value % i == 0) {
          prime = true;
          break;
      }
   }
   isPrime.answers[value] = prime;
 }
 return isPrime.answers[value];
}
```

I quess this way it would be much clearer. But maybe they wanted you to teach you all those short cuts. I don't know. The above code is the same what happens in the original version. You see there are some more additional lines since I did not use the assignment also represents result thingy JavaScript offers (and in an extend Java, too).

Answer (score 0):

You assign to prime the boolean value that the comparison `value != 1` returns